# Android - debugging row layout and not sure what file is being referenced

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have this layout for a screen with a list of things on it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

<include android:id="@+id/header"
         layout="@layout/header"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>    

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/loading_questions" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text for please wait while questions load.  If the questions do not load, check your Internet connection. Questions are stored in a secure remote database so that you do not lose your work."
    android:textSize="12sp"
    />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">        
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

In my code, I load it like this:

ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

and then populate it like this:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

// My data
private List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps, R.layout.questions_list,
        new String[] {"train", "to"}, 
        new int[] {R.id.TRAIN_CELL,  R.id.TO_CELL});
// This was the middle item R.id.FROM_CELL,

list.setAdapter(adapter);       
list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

and then when items load, I just re-populate this adapter.

Here is the questions_list.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:paddingTop="4dip"
     android:paddingBottom="6dip"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:textSize="13sp">

     <TextView android:id="@+id/TRAIN_CELL"
         android:layout_width="275dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/TO_CELL"
         android:layout_width="25dip"
         android:textSize="20sp"
         android:textStyle="bold" 
         android:gravity="center"
         android:src="@drawable/arrow_button"
         android:textColor="@color/light_best_blue"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
         android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And it does render the list with two columns, but the problem is that it disables my header navigation (the buttons no longer work), and there is a white border around the header as well.

Would anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: try height of ListView as wrap_content

Comment: @Shrikant trying right now... :)

Comment: @Shrikant that didn't work. The header navigation buttons are still disabled for some reason.

Comment: Can you post the image of listView, so I can understand the problem better?

Comment: @Shrikant do you mean a screen shot?

Comment: Yes. please post the screen shot.

Comment: @Shrikant I just took a photo of the emulator and uploaded it...its easier than doing the screenshot on a windows-based computer.  You see the header navigation on top? That thing is disabled for some reason.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16369/discussion-between-shrikant-and-genadinik)